# How to send window object from active tab to extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage

I need to get user storage data (local and session) from certain tab as in [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-storage-manager-all/giompennnhheakjcnobejbnjgbbkmdnd) app (screen below).

As I understanding - I need to get window object from active Tab. I have got an object but i can use it in console from current tab.

[image]

I need use it in extension's console (how?). My goal it is show this data in table (here is no problem).

[image]

---

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Test extension",
"description": "...",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
},

"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "unlimitedStorage"
]
}
```

---

**popup.js**

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    var obj = chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
        var tabId = tabs[0].id;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code:'var w = window; console.log(w);'});

    });
});
```

---

How can I send window object from tab console to extension console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Node js to achieve thie goal. Look at the video from [Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkb_x9ZN0Vo).
[Link](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to repository.

Answer (score 0):

[`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) has a callback parameter, its value is the result (**array**) of the script, so you could just use the following code to get `window` object of current web page:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code:'window;'}, function(results) {
    console.log(results[0]);
});
```

Comment: By using this returns NULL. Window == null

Comment: @ArtemSolovev, basically `window` and `window.window` points to the same object, I'm not sure `window.window` is `null` here, but you could just use `results[0]` as `window`, don't need to call `results[0].window`

Comment: There is no localStorage property or sessionStorage. I need them